# Formal product of cycles in a permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Dixon's book *Permutation Groups*, there is a sentence saying that in a symmetric group $Sym(\Omega)$, "the second common way to specify a permutation is to write $x$ as a product of disjoint cycles...(this product is only a formal product in the case that $\Omega$ is infinite".

What is the difference between a product and a formal product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a discrete group, that is, just an algebraic structure, with no topology (compatible with the operation) you cannot take an infinite product of elements, only a finite one.

So when $\Omega$ is infinite, the product of possibly infinitely many cycles is not a product in the ordinary sense of (discrete) group theory - hence the term *formal*.

This *formal product* makes sense as a function, though, because since the cycles in it are disjoint, one may distinguish two possibilities for the action of the product on an element $x$.

1. Either all cycles fix $x$, and then the product fixes $x$,
2. or there is exactly one cycle $c$, which moves the element $x$ to an element $x c$ in the same cycle, while all other cycles fix both $x$ and $x c$, and thus have no bearing.

Of course one may argue that the second case includes the first one when $c = (x)$, although in this case $c$ does not actually move $x$.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more about what does it mean by "a product in the ordinary sense of discrete group"? And why infinite product is not allowed in a discrete group? Thanks!

Comment: Consider the additive group of the integers, and the infinite sum $1+1+1+\dots$